# Get MAX inputted date within sub query

Tags: mysql, join, subquery

I have a script which is working but not as desired. My aim is to select the most recently inputted record on the `plans` database for each seller in the `account_manager_sellers` list.

The current issue with the script below is: It is returning the oldest record rather than the newest, for example: it is selecting a record in 2016 rather than one which has a timestamp in 2018. (eventually I need to change the WHERE clause to get all `lastsale` records before 2017-01-01.

### Simple Database Samples.

`plans` AKA (sales list)

```
+----+------------------+-----------+
| id |   plan_written   | seller_id |
+----+------------------+-----------+
|  1 | 20/09/2016 09:12 |       123 |
|  2 | 22/12/2016 09:45 |       444 |
|  3 | 19/10/2016 09:07 |       555 |
|  4 | 02/10/2015 14:26 |       123 |
|  5 | 15/08/2016 11:06 |       444 |
|  6 | 16/08/2016 11:03 |       123 |
|  7 | 03/10/2016 10:15 |       555 |
|  8 | 28/09/2016 10:12 |       123 |
|  9 | 27/09/2016 15:12 |       444 |
+----+------------------+-----------+
```

`account_manager_sellers` (seller list)

```
+-----+----------+
| id  |   name   |
+-----+----------+
| 123 | person 1 |
| 444 | person 2 |
| 555 | person 3 |
+-----+----------+
```

### Current Code Used

```
SELECT p.plan_written, p.seller_id
FROM plans AS p NATURAL JOIN (
         SELECT   id, MAX(plan_written) AS lastsale
         FROM     plans
         GROUP BY seller_id
       ) AS t
JOIN account_manager_sellers AS a ON a.id = p.seller_id
WHERE  lastsale < "2018-05-08 00:00:00"
```

### Summary

Using the code and example tables above, this code would return these 3 results, whilst we do expect 3 results, the MAX(`plan_written`) does not seem to have followed, my guess is that it is something to do with the GROUP clause, I am not sure if we can utilise an ORDER BY and LIMIT clause?

```
+--------------+------------------+
| seller_id    |   plan_written   |
+--------------+------------------+
|          123 | 16/08/2016 11:03 |
|          444 | 15/08/2016 11:06 |
|          555 | 03/10/2016 10:15 |
+--------------+------------------+
```

Comment: Why are you doing two joins if you only have two tables? This not an efficient way to do it. IMO you should select id and max date from already joined tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The join condition in your query is off, and you should be restricting to the max date for each seller.  Also, you don't need to join to the `account_manager_sellers` table to get your expected output:

```
SELECT p1.*
FROM plans p1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT
        seller_id, MAX(plan_written) AS max_plan_written
    FROM plans
    WHERE plan_written < '2018-05-08 00:00:00'
    GROUP BY seller_id
) p2
    ON p1.seller_id = p2.seller_id AND
       p1.plan_written = p2.max_plan_written;
```

Comment: I am not storing as text, sorry, this was excel formatting my example it is a proper timestamp.

Comment: Perfect, many thanks, been at this one for a few days on and off now, and this works, I have no idea why the other solutions have not worked, maybe because it is an INNER rather than NATURAL join IDK but it works after some tests, thanks again.

Comment: @PeterBennett I didn't comment on the natural join (some love it, some hate it), but in this case it certainly does not make it easier to understand the join condition.  But your bigger problem was not restricting the outer table to the max date, and the check on the plan written date needs to be inside the subquery.

Comment: Oh and the only reason I wanted to join the account_manager_sellers, was so I could append their email to the results, but I am sure I can work this out.